# Error when installing .apk on Linux beta in Chrome OS

Tags: android, linux, apk, adb, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to install an apk file in the Linux terminal on my Chromebook, so I followed instructions from [this website](https://content.techgig.com/how-to-sideload-android-apps-without-developer-mode-on-chrome-os/articleshow/73012402.cms). So I installed the ADB and ran `adb connect 100.115.92.2:5555`, and after that I tried installing my apk by running `adb install opinionrewards.apk` but it returned this error:

```
error: more than one device/emulator
adb: error: failed to get feature set: more than one device/emulator
- waiting for device -
error: more than one device/emulator
```

Can someone please explain why this error occurred and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, all I had to do was `adb kill-server` and then start it again, and just install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install filename.apk
```